# SWTBOT doesn't delete components and keep adding others

Tags: java, junit, swtbot

the problem that I am facing is the following:
I am doing a SWTBot test in which I create a few composites, delete them, adding others and so on. The problem is that, after each start of the test, the SWTBot test doesn't start from an initial state, it is just appending elements, not delete the old ones and insert new elements.
Can you please, say to me, what should I do in order to make the SWTBot test starting from the beginning each time I run the test?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question will get more traction if you include code snippets, better yet with complete issue replication.

Answer (score 0):

A test in general has to clean up its environment after execution. That's what the method tearDown and annotations @After and @AfterClass are meant for.

If your test cleans the application when closing, then next tests should work better.